# Unicode Error using pandas: read_hdf

Tags: python, pandas

After having searched in every forum/page/site, I can´t fix my problem.
I am trying to read a .h5 file with pandas and I've got this message:
`"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 35120: ordinal not in range(128)"`. This message appears when I am trying to read both h5 and csv files.
I have tried different ways to fix it, but I can`t and I hope you can save me pls!

```
cch_365_8760_pivot=pd.read_hdf('CCH_MOD.h5','CCH_MOD')

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.5.1.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 15.5.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None

pandas: 0.18.0
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 8.1.1
setuptools: 20.3
Cython: 0.23.4
numpy: 1.10.4
scipy: 0.17.0
statsmodels: 0.6.1
xarray: None
IPython: 4.1.2
sphinx: 1.3.5
patsy: 0.4.0
dateutil: 2.5.1
pytz: 2016.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.0.0
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.5
matplotlib: 1.5.1
openpyxl: 2.3.2
xlrd: 0.9.4
xlwt: 1.0.0
xlsxwriter: 0.8.4
lxml: 3.6.0
bs4: 4.4.1
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 1.0.12
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.8
boto: 2.39.0
```

Also I am using Mac OSX el capitán 64 bits.
I hope you can help me. I`ve been dealing with this issue about 3 days and  I don't know what to do.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after try differents things, i just ran my code with python 2.7 and it did work. I guess there is a bug with this or there is a different way to do that, but I choose the easy way. Thank you all!